# javascript code return nothing (nan/emptystring/no issues) what's wrong?

Tags: javascript

i just started learning to code, but everytime i run my code it's just return nothing/nan/no issues/ empty string, but when i copy people's code it's working even it's the exact same code that i type. i've tried to copy someone's code then it's work, but when i change the operator
ex : from ++ to -- and from < to > it's return no issues in console

```js
var sp = '';

for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    for (var j = 1; j <= i ; j++) {
        for (var k = 1; k > i; k--){

        sp += '*';
    }
    }
    sp += '\n';
}
console.log(sp);
```

Comment: In your code 'k' starts with a value of 1, and can only down; and 'i' starts with a value of 1 and only goes up. So 'k > i' will never be true.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think k should be from 10 to i

If I make a change like that it gives me the following pattern.

```js
var sp = '';

for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    for (var j = 1; j <= i ; j++) {
        for (var k = 10; k > i; k--) {
           sp += '*';
        }
    }
    sp += '\n';
}
console.log(sp);
```

Hope this helps, let me know if this solved the issue

Comment: thank you @p2pdops for the correction!, but will my code returning nothing?
here's my another code that returns nothing
 ` var totalBike = 10; var operatedBike = 5;
 for( var bikeNumber = 1; bikeNumber >= totalBike; bikeNumber++ ){
 if ( bikeNumber <= 5 ){ 
console.log("bike number " + bikeNumber + " can be used");
 } else { console.log("bike number " + bikeNumber + " can not used")
 } 
}`

Comment: Try this ```var totalBike = 10, operatedBike = 5;
for (var i = 1; i <= totalBike; i++) console.log(`bike number ${i} can ${i > operatedBike ? 'not' : ''} be used`);```

Comment: that's working!! but i'm not in that level yet, i'll trying to
big thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

You are starting `k = 1` and checking it with `k > i` which will never be possible

It fails after the first check

`i = 1` --> `k = 1` and `(k > i) --> 1 > 1` ------- `FAIL`

`i = 2` --> `k = 1` and `(k > i) --> 1 > 2` ------- `FAIL`

It will fail every time